# Why is my python (exe file) shutting off after logging in using static token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, pyinstaller

I have a problem starting my discord.py Bot with the .exe file that pyinstaller created from my main.py.

After i start the main.exe in the "dist" folder, a python shell terminal starts like it should. But immediately after the discord.client trys logging in using static token ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xUxV.png)) the file just closes without any errors.

I tried looking up the problem but nothing seems to be in region of my problem.
This is why i am asking here for help.

Here is my Code from the main.py, which got converted to the main.exe:

```
import discord
import cfg
from discord.ext import commands

class Client(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('.'), intents=discord.Intents().all())
        self.cogslist = cfg.COGSLIST

    async def setup_hook(self):
      for ext in self.cogslist:
        await self.load_extension(ext)

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Game(name="Under construction!"))
        print(f"Logged in as {self.user.name}")

        synced = await self.tree.sync()
        print("Slash CMDs Synced " + str(len(synced)) + " Commands")

        ttv_cog = self.get_cog("ttvnotify")
        if ttv_cog:
            ttv_cog.check_twitch_online_streamers.start()

bot = Client()

bot.run(cfg.TOKEN)
```

Comment: You say your problem is the static token. Are you sure? Did you build the thing with passing token differently before and it worked? Because I'd say it's pyinstaller being pyinstaller - python is not designed to be bundled in exe, it breaks a lot of times